# Python from django.contrib.auth.views import logout ImportError: cannot import name 'logout'

Tags: python, django, logout

I have configured my python env with python 3.5, but I am getting the following error when I run my server with the command `python manage.py runserver`

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
ImportError: cannot import name 'logout'
```

this is my config

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1a.1
gunicorn==19.8.1
numpy==1.14.3
psycopg2==2.7.4
pytz==2018.4
whitenoise==4.0b4
```

I tried reinstalling my env and changing python version but issue stills happening.

Thanks for your questions guys

Comment: Since django-1.11, the login, logout, etc. function-based views have been rewritten to (class-based  views)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906537/2351696]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey looks like you are using the wrong django version, `django.contrib.auth.views.logout` is not available in your current django version, try downgrading your django version to a lower version with this command: 
`sudo pip install Django==2.0.2` 
or change the import in order to use `logout_view`

Answer (score 27):

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'django.contrib.auth.views'
```

I had this error and looked up for a solution found it here. [Remove views from import](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin/issues/602)

Works for me in Python 3.7 and Django 2.2. No need to downgrade to Django 2.0.4(as LTS is in 2.2)

It was this one that caused me the error.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

Had to change it to

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

Worked for logout too.

Comment: @MenoTx asked about logout, so the working change that worked for me is: from django.contrib.auth import login

Comment: @sunsetjunks you mean logout? LOL

Comment: right, my bad. You can guess this from my context :)

Answer (score 3):

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

it's work for me on django 3.0.x

Answer (score 2):

this is for django `2.x`, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out)

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I added to `urls.py` to get login working:

```
def my_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('index')
```

along with `urlpatterns`:

```
path('logout/', my_logout, name="logout"),
```

Works for me in Python 2.7, Django 2.1.5!

Comment: cannot import name 'my_logout' from 'account.views'
this kind of error are seen, whenever i tried the code as above.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Django (django == 3.2.4) the import should be the following

`from django.contrb.auth.views import LogoutView`

Answer (score -1):

Pyhton is very case sensitive... make sure your code lines up with proper whitespace. I go this error and make functions created in views.py were not aligned

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).