# Django cannot import login from django.contrib.auth.views

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I try to build a login function for my page. To edit the urls.py as followed, it keeps printing this:

> cannot import name 'login' from 'django.contrib.auth.views'

How could I deal with the problem?

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", 
         login, 
         {"template_name": "users/login.html"}, 
         name="login"),
]
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I used the version django 2.1

Comment: There were removed in 2.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1

Comment: Thx. Just got it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11), the `login`, `logout`, etc. function-based views have been rewritten to class-based views: the [**`LoginView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and [**`LogoutView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) classes, as is specified in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#id2). The "old" function-based views could still be used, but were marked as *deprecated*.

In [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), the old function-based views have been removed, as specified in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1).

You can write it like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', 
        LoginView.as_view(
            template_name='users/login.html'
        ), 
        name="login"
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## try this

```
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Willem Van Onsem's answer worked for me. On an implementation note, if you rather keep your view code separate from urls (also if you have some processing to do), you would write your `urls.py` like this (based on a per-app `urls.py` file in your app folder which means you have to include it in the overall `urlpatterns` of the project's `urls.py` file which is in the same folder as your `settings.py` file, with the syntax `path('', include('users.urls')),`):

```
    from django.urls import path

    from .views import (
        login_view
    )

    app_name = "userNamespace"
    urlpatterns = [
      path('login/', loginView.as_view(), name="login-view"),
    ]
```

and over in your views.py file you would have something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView,
)
from users.models import User

class login_view(LoginView):
    # The line below overrides the default template path of <appname>/<modelname>_login.html
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html' # Where accounts/login.html is the path under the templates folder as defined in your settings.py file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Login page.
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: With Django 3.1.1 this updates from for Django 2.1 works to answer the above question. thanks.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27115370)

Answer (score 0):

Can try this to create a login form

```
# views page
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib import messages

def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)

#urls
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),,
]
```