# "AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'password_reset' " error in urls.py

Tags: python, django, passwords

I am using Django 3.0.5 and python 3.6 and getting the error from the terminal as :
" AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'password_reset' "  in my urls.py file.

urls.py

````
 ```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path
 from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from blog import views
 urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('index/',views.index, name='index'),
 path('datetime/',views.current_datetime,name='datetime'),
 path('',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
 url(r'^blog/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.post_detail,name="post_detail"),
 url('post_create/',views.post_create,name = "post_create"),
 url('login/', views.user_login,name="user_login"),
url('logout/', views.user_logout,name="user_logout"),


#Password reset urls

url('password-reset/',auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url('password-reset/done/',auth_views.password_reset_done,name="password_reset_done"),
url('password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/',auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm"),
url('password-reset/complete/', auth_views.password_reset_complete,name="password_reset_complete"),
 ]


 ```
````

I have checked [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/)    which is talking about the same 4 views which I have written then why I am getting the error. When I change "auth_views.password_reset" to "auth_views.PasswordResetForm in "url('password-reset/',auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset')" then, terminal does not show any error for "password_reset" but then it shows error for "password_reset_done".
 Can anyone please tell why I am getting this error and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51906428/67579 The function-based views are gone, now only *class-based views* are used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could help,

[auth urls source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py)

```
    from django.contrib.auth import views
    from django.urls import path

    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
        path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

        path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
        path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),

        path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
        path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
        path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
        path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    ]
```