# ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'django.contrib.auth.views'

Tags: python, django

My Code :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

app_name='accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home , name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$' , login , {'template_name':'login.html'})

]'
```

And Error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'django.contrib.auth.views' (C:\Python\Notes\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django cannot import login from django.contrib.auth.views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906428/django-cannot-import-login-from-django-contrib-auth-views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

app_name='accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home , name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$' , LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'))

]'
```

Comment: Yes. It works thank you so much